# Website sending a hash string on the click of a button

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, hash, python-requests

I'm trying to create a script for [this website](https://gleam.io/SamwN/the-tablo-podcast-signed-merch-giveaway) (That will emulate click of the green additional entries button).

After intercepting the packages sent using Burpsuite I see the following:

[image]

from the JSON dictionary, I have no problem in recreating any of the keys apart of the `h`. After further investigation, I found that the value changes every time one clicks the button. currently my code looks like this:

```
import requests

url = "https://gleam.io:443/enter/SamwN/4656663"
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0", "Origin": "https://gleam.io", "Referer": "https://gleam.io/SamwN/the-tablo-podcast-signed-merch-giveaway"}

json={"details": "DIVE Studios", "f": "fada9366d9971b126f3edfc27f52b0bb.9ddf471da4a07b2bc50d16af4008ba4d", "grecaptcha_response": None, "h": "f8dfd39a929adc136223b2e0d59de1fb"}

requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=json)
```

Is there any way to get the value of the `h` without using Selenium? many thanks in advance

Comment: you can try to find JavaScript which generates `h` and recreate this code in Python. But usually it is very complex problem and Selenium (or similar tools) seems much easier.

Comment: @furas do you know any tutorial or questions here that could help me with this?

Comment: to work with Selenium you have [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and [Elemental Selenium](https://elementalselenium.com/). To find JavaScript code and recreate it in Python: I don't know any tutorial - it is too complex.